# Can't get the result from a PHP script with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs, casperjs

I'am trying to call a `PHP script` on my local server with `jQuery` inside an `CasperJS` function, but somehow I don't get the result. Here is my code:

```
casper.then(function() {
    var result = casper.evaluate(function() {
        var result = $.get('http://localhost/test.php', function() {});
        return result;
    });
    result = JSON.stringify(result);
    this.echo(result);
    this.exit();
});
```

It does not matter which URL is called, it delivers always the same result:

```
{"abort":{},"always":{},"complete":{},"done":{},"error":null,"fail":{},"getAllRe
sponseHeaders":{},"getResponseHeader":{},"overrideMimeType":{},"pipe":null,"prog
ress":{},"promise":{},"readyState":1,"setRequestHeader":{},"state":{},"statusCod
e":{},"success":null,"then":{}}
```

Things I have checked:

- XAMP server is running and working
- PHP file is there
- Any other URL also does not work and delivers the result (see above)
- Also the jQuery function `$.load()` does not work (the result is then "null")
- jQuery is loaded correctly (otherwise CasperJS throws an error)
- If I simply return it works correctly (eg `return "test";`)

Don't know what to do. Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend changing your async to false in `$.ajaxSetup();`

and also, you should get your return data from within the callback success function

```
casper.then(function() {
    var result = casper.evaluate(function() {

        var $return = ''; // initiate $return

        var async = $.ajaxSetup()['async'];
        $.ajaxSetup({'async':false}); // Set async to false

        $.get('http://localhost/test.php', function( data ) {

            $return = data; // test.php return data is saved to $return

        });

        $.ajaxSetup({'async': async }); // Set async to back to original value

    });
    result = JSON.stringify($return);
    this.echo(result);
    this.exit();
});
```

The only downside to this, thanks to 
[Esailija](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995876/esailijaEsailija) for pointing it out, is that your page will 'hang' until the request is completed

Comment: Awesome, it works, thank you very much!! After your solution I had to add "webSecurityEnabled: false", but that's another story.

Comment: You are not mentioning the downsides of this, for user the page will appear to be crashed while the request is pending. You can't really notice this in development because the responses are instant anyway.

Comment: @Esailija Yes, the page will appear to hang **IF** you are running this script before the DOM is loaded. If you are running this after, there would just be a delay in response.

Comment: No, sync requests always freeze the tab (or entire browser) for the duration of the request regardless when its made.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. That is the downside to setting async to false, adding it to my answer

Comment: @Esailija You're right, but that thing is for a crawler. He doesn't care :-)

Comment: @Crayl Well generally in stackoverflow, answers are supposed to help more than one person (otherwise your question will be closed as Too Localized). Some of those might care about the downside :P

Answer (score 1):

`$.get` is asynchronous, its result won't be available until
the callback is called.

```
casper.then(function() {
    var _this = this;
    casper.evaluate(function() {
        $.get('http://localhost/test.php', function(result) {
            _this.echo(result);
            _this.exit();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere on the jQuery docs for $.get() does $.get() return the contents of the page. You're using the http transport instance.